# Registering user with specific email to specific role

Tags: c#, api, identity, roles

I'm trying to create an register method that I have in controller:

```
[HttpPost("register")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterUser(UserForRegisterDto userForRegisterDto)
    {
        var userToCreate = _mapper.Map<User>(userForRegisterDto);
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userToCreate, userForRegisterDto.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return Ok();
        }

        return BadRequest();
    }
```

I'm trying to add role with specific email address (for example: every email service with '*@example.com gets' role 'Member').

I know that is operator [like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) but I have very little knowledge to use with it.

Is there any other way than using that operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can use EndsWith:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.endswith)

```
var role = "None";
if (userForRegisterDto.EmailAddress.EndsWith("@example.com"))
{
   role = "Member";
}
else if (userForRegisterDto.EmailAddress.EndsWith("@myownsite.com"))
{
   role = "Admin";
}
```